# String and variable to output variable

Tags: php, string, variables

My intention is to output `$car1`, `$car2` to have a list in the HTML output e.g Toyota, BMW, ...However i am getting `$car2` in the HTML output. How does one make the loop output `$car1`, `$car2`... Is there another function other than echo to do this?

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    echo $car . $i;
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: `echo` is not a function, and you mean `<br />`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   $varName = "car" . $i;
   echo $$varName . "<br />";
}
```

or, for short:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
   echo ${'car' . $i} . "<br />";
}
```

You'd be better off with [arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php), though.

Comment: @BenMatewe: No worries. Don't forget to check out arrays.

Comment: Thanks. They certainly are very powerful and have shrinked my code dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing:

You have a bunch of variables called:

- $car1
- $car2
- $car3
- $car4
- ...

And now you want to output them using this:

```
echo $car . $i;
```

So you want the code the generate `$car1` for you?

<strike>This won't work.</strike> You shouldn't do this. You should use an [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) to save your cars. This can be looped over using a for or [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)-loop.

Comment: It can work. It's not the nicest approach, but "this won't work" is incorrect.

Comment: Oh. I had to test it myself until I believed it, but you're right. Anyways, arrays are the thing to use here.

Answer (score 0):

As Tomalak mentioned, arrays should be used in this case.

```
$car[] = "Honda";
$car[] = "Toyota";
$car[] = "Dodge";
$car[] = "Ford";

for($i = 0; $i<=3; $i++){
  echo $car[$i];
  echo "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
Honda
Toyota
Dodge
Ford
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Point on arrays noted.